# Select first immediate child without a specific class, for each parent with a specific class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, traversal

I want to create a script which will add a class to the first child without a specific class, for each parent with a specifice class.
For example:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <p class="no">1. Not this one please</p>
  <div>
    <p>2. not this either</p>
  </div>
  <p>3. Make this red!</p>
  <p>4. Not this</p>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <p class="no">5. Not this one please</p>
  <p>6. Make this red also!</p>
  <p>7. Not this</p>
</div>
```

My javascript is as follows:

```
$('div.wrap').find('p:not(.no):first').addClass('red');
```

This will select descendent without `class="no"`, as opposed to the first child (so item 2, as opposed to item 3 in the above example). 
I've tried changing `.find` to `.children`, but then it only selects the first example on the page, not the first in each set (so only item 2 in the above example, not item 6).

Here is a codepen illustrating the above http://cdpn.io/izGDH

Comment: is there a purely CSS way to do it? Not using any preprocessors or JS...
I tried combining a pseudo-class selector and a combinator, but it does not seem to work. Something like this:
`.parent > * :first-child`

Comment: found the solution to my pure CSS way problem on a [discord server](https://discordapp.com/channels/435107908175527946/435120136517582868)
`.parent > :first-child`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are very close!  You want to add a directive to only grab direct descendants: ">"

```
$('div.wrap').find('> p:not(.no):first').addClass('red');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wnewby/HUqR9/

Answer (score 0):

This is one way:

```
$('div.wrap p.no').each(function(){ $(this).siblings('p').first().addClass('red'); })
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/KmWk6/)**